# Have no info about video driver (ASUS-PRO50/20.04)

Tags: 20.04, gpu-driver

I'm trying to use UBUNTU 20.04 on my old laptop ASUS PRO50 with a Radeon HD3458/3478 graphics card.
But I have a lot of troubles...

Question is:
when typing

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
```

I got only:

> configuration: latency=0

On a clean install, also after an installed PPA driver.
Why? And where is the video driver?

Comment: The graphics driver is *radeon*, the only one still supporting that graphics card/chip. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I couldn't find any info about radeon. Also I have a problem with booting system, only through recovery mode and only in the low tesolution.